# Is it possible to pass a function argument into a decorator?

Tags: python, discord, python-decorators, pycord

```py
def my_decorator(func):

    def inner():
        """do stuff with arg"""
        func()

        return func

    return inner

@my_decorator
def my_func(arg):
    pass
```

I wish to make the argument passed to the function `my_function()` to be passed to the decorator `my_decorator()`. I know it is possible to pass a variable to the decorator by putting it in a call like this: `@my_decorator("arg")`, but I am using the pycord library, which passes arguments directly to the function.

Is there any way to do it in Python, or will I have to find another way?

I could put this code in the function itself, but if the code is expanded later, it could cause problems, and it's way easier to maintain and update a single decorator/wrapper than change multiple places in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes – your `def inner():` should be `def inner(arg):`; after all, the function you return from the decorator effectively replaces the original function.

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def inner(arg):
        print(f"Going to increase {arg} by 1 before passing it to func!")
        return func(arg + 1)
    return inner

@my_decorator
def my_func(arg):
    print(f"my_func: {arg}")

my_func(9)
```

prints out

```
Going to increase 9 by 1 before passing it to func!
my_func: 10
```

Comment: This solution is bad beccause it makes decorator accept only one argument and adds 1 to argument (?). Point of the decorator is to use in many functions, not only one.

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw Depends on the decorator. A completely general generator like timeit, yes. However, some decorators are not completely general and operate on specific function signatures.

Comment: Point of the decorator is to do something before or after the function. There is no point for decorator to be designed for only one function.

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw Yes, there is no point in creating a decorator for a single function. But that's not what I said or what this answer demonstrates. It's defined for one *function signature*.  It all depends on the actual use case of the decorator. Some decorators might operate on specific arguments passed to the function, or on the return type.

Comment: Hard disagree — there are lots of cases of more specialized decorators.  A less trivial example would be a decorator that does class-specific logging and depends on the first arg (self) being of a specific type so it can extract information from it.

Comment: This answer (even if this particular example is not something you’d do in actual practice) also does a better job IMO of demonstrating the relationship between `inner` and the decorated `my_func`.

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw _"Point of the decorator is to do something before or after the function."_ Nonsense. That is _one_ potential use case for decorators, but by no means the only one. Since a decorator is itself just a function (that happens to take another function as its first argument), the number of possible applications is endless. And so are the possible restrictions you can impose on your decorator. One of them being "use only on functions that take a single argument".

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw Arguably the most famous example of a decorator is the built-in `@property`. Intended only for methods that take **exactly one argument**, the instance of the owner class (typically called `self`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible and could be achieved using `*args` amd `**kwargs`

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        """do stuff with arg"""
        func(*args, **kwargs)

        return func

    return inner


@my_decorator
def my_func(arg):
    pass
```

Comment: This makes `my_func`'s runtime signature `(*args, **kwargs)`, which is likely not desired.